# how to access a Fragment from the inner AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I have a `Fragment` and inner `AsyncTask` that loads a text:

```
public class TextReaderFragment extends Fragment {
    LoadTextTask task = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);

        task=new LoadTextTask();
        task.execute();
        ...
    }

    public void renderText() {
        ...
    }

    class LoadTextTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // how to access Fragment or Activity here?
            ProgressBar loader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.textLoadingProgressBar);
            loader.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean loaded) {
            // how to trigger renderText method defined on TextReaderFragment?
            loader.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        }
```

I don't understand how I can:

1. Access `Fragment` or `Activity` from `onPreExecute()` method to get to UI widgets defined in `Fragment` or `Activity`
2. Trigger `renderText()` method defined in `TextReaderFragment` from `onPostExecute()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers point-wise:

- The `Fragment` can be accessed as `TextReaderFragment.this`.
- The `Activity` can be accessed as `(MyActivity)getActivity()`.
- `renderText()` can be called using `TextReaderFragment.this.renderText()`.

Comment: thanks! Is it a common approach to place `AsyncTask` inside parent class and call parent class methods when task is complete?

Comment: Indeed. If you want to avoid copy-pasting the same `AsyncTask` code everywhere, its possible to create a common public class and use either interfaces or lambdas (Java 8) to call the methods defined in the `Activity` or `Fragment` ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't declare your AsyncTask `static` it implicitly has a reference to it's enclosing class.  To reference the enclosing class's instance, you have to use the fully qualified class name with the this keyword, or `TextReaderFragment.this` in your case.

For a more detailed explanation on how nested classes work, see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial.